# ul not lining up with radio button

Tags: css, list, radio-button, styling

```
input{
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: disc outside none;
  margin-top: -16px;
}

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked></input>
  <ul>
    <li>I want this to be one line up, in line w/ the button</li>
    <li>Lots of text here...</li>
    <li>One more item</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"></input>
</form>
```

I have a form that has several radio buttons as answers, some of which contain bullets points.  I want the bullet points to begin on the same line as the radio button, but I'm having a hard time setting it up.  A negative margin works, but it seems like there has to be a better way.  See image here: [radio_ul](https://s3.amazonaws.com/zardopix/radio_ul)

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're not using a reset, but that screenshot doesn't look like default browser styling. Nevertheless, looks like you need to remove the margin or padding on the `ul`. In your stylesheet try the following:

```
form ul { margin-left: 0; }
```

or

```
form ul { padding-left: 0; }
```

Using a class name for the lists within the form isn't a bad idea either.
Hope that helps.